# How do I create a job queue using a MailboxProcessor?

Tags: f#

I'm trying to model a asynchronous job processing framework using MailboxProcessor. My requirements are to Start, Stop, Pause, and Resume the job processor. Can I build Pause / Resume functionality with MailboxProcessor? Also I should be able to Stop and Start? I'm trying to model after Windows Service.

I've a system in C#, implemented using Queue / Threads. I was looking for design alternatives, that's when I saw MailboxProcessor. I believe I can use it but couldnt figure out how to handle the above scenarios. So is it possible to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sure :) Just hold an internal queue of jobs and enumerate through the queue when the job processor is in Start mode. In any other mode, just enqueue new jobs until the processor goes into start mode.

```
type 'a msg =       // '
    | Start
    | Stop
    | Pause
    | Job of (unit -> unit)

type processQueue() =        
    let mb = MailboxProcessor.Start(fun inbox ->
        let rec loop state (jobs : System.Collections.Generic.Queue<_>) =
            async {
                if state = Start then
                    while jobs.Count > 0 do
                        let f = jobs.Dequeue()
                        f()

                let! msg = inbox.Receive()
                match msg with
                | Start -> return! loop Start jobs
                | Pause -> return! loop Pause jobs
                | Job(f) -> jobs.Enqueue(f); return! loop state jobs
                | Stop -> return ()
            }
        loop Start (new System.Collections.Generic.Queue<_>()))

    member this.Resume() = mb.Post(Start)
    member this.Stop() = mb.Post(Stop)
    member this.Pause() = mb.Post(Pause)
    member this.QueueJob(f) = mb.Post(Job f)
```

This class behaves as expected: You can enqueue jobs in the Pause state, but they'll only run in the Start state. Once the processQueue is stopped, it can't be restarted, and none of the enqueued jobs will run (its easy enough to change this behavior so that, rather than killing the queue, it just doesn't enqueue a job in the Stop state).

Use [MailboxProcessor.PostAndReply](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/MailboxProcessor#Two-way_Communication) if you need two-way communication between the mailbox processor and your code.

Comment: +1 Slight improvement: you can make the code clearer by making the states explicit. Then you can also encapsulate all of the state in a `state` type and, in particular, only the `Paused` state would have a queue. Also, you might like to represent the states as mutually recursive asynchronous workflows...

Comment: Wouldn't this block on the job queue until it finishes? That would seem to make `Pause` have no effect.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to check out [Luca's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/lucabol/), as I think it has [some](http://blogs.msdn.com/lucabol/archive/2009/05/29/lagent-an-agent-framework-in-f-part-i-workers-and-parallelworkers.aspx) [recent](http://blogs.msdn.com/lucabol/archive/2009/06/05/lagent-an-agent-framework-in-f-part-ii-agents-and-control-messages.aspx) [relevant](http://blogs.msdn.com/lucabol/archive/2009/06/12/lagent-an-agent-framework-in-f-part-iii-default-error-management.aspx) [stuff](http://blogs.msdn.com/lucabol/archive/2009/06/19/lagent-an-agent-framework-in-f-part-iv-custom-error-management.aspx).

Comment: Luca's blog still appears to be there, but the four specific links no longer land on the correct pages.