# The correct way to override Equals etc. in DU with CustomEquality and CustomComparison?

Tags: f#

I came across a situation where I'd like compare a discriminated union that has one case which isn't comparable directly and that I have no need to use in (custom) comparison. For that reason, I wrote `CustomEquality` and `CustomComparison` functions. Alas I get a stackoverflow and in general I'm uncertain how to handle this kind of a equality override situation in F#. I read [Equality and Comparison Constraints in F#](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsyme/archive/2009/11/08/equality-and-comparison-constraints-in-f-1-9-7.aspx) by **Don Syme**, **Chris Smith's** [F# Language Details (Gotchas)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chrsmith/archive/2009/11/09/f-language-details-gotchas.aspx).

**<edit:** As pointed out in the comments and as for context, what should be done with the `Funky` case? I was entertaining a similar idea to [How do I create a job queue using a MailboxProcessor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041195/how-do-i-create-a-job-queue-using-a-mailboxprocessor) wherein I'd queue DUs that could be used to perform functions or to control a state machine.

Looking at that other post (I refrain from producing the code here), which uses elegantly `MailboxProcessor` I see it has a similar problem and somewhat similar idea. I'm not sure if the design could be better or is there a way to compare functions and in any event I have some more questions regarding this (with a C# background).

**Questions:**

- How to avoid the stackoverflow in the `Equals`? (Probably something simple, but...)
- Should the generic `IComparable` implemented?
- Should `static member (=)` etc. be overloaded as per Chris' blog post?
- What else should be overloaded in DUs in similar situation? Should `IEquatable` be implemented in case there are performance implementations?

I think some of these could be answered by looking at the IL (e.g. if the compiler already generates `IEquatable` for DUs), but just to make sure I haven't overlooked anything.

The code

```
[<CustomEquality; CustomComparison>]
type FunkyUnion =
    | Case1
    | Case2
    | Funky of (unit -> unit)

    override x.Equals(obj) =
        //This here will cause a stackoverflow to occur...
        match obj with
        |  :? FunkyUnion as y -> (x = y)
        |  _ -> false

    override x.GetHashCode() =
        match x with
        | Case1 -> 1
        | Case2 -> 2
        | _     -> 3

    interface System.IComparable with
       member x.CompareTo yobj = 
          match yobj with 
          | :? FunkyUnion as y -> compare x y
          | _ -> invalidArg "yobj" "cannot compare value of different types"

    interface System.IComparable<FunkyUnion> with
        member x.CompareTo(y) =
            compare x y

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 

    let funky1 = FunkyUnion.Case1
    let funky2 = FunkyUnion.Case2

    if funky1 = funky2 then
        printfn "!!!"

    printfn "!"

    0
```

Comment: How do you want to equate `Funky` values? Are you looking for same reference? Or do you want to say to two `Funky` values can never be equal to one another?

Comment: The idea is to avoid comparing funky values, I'll update the question.

Comment: Well, what happens then when two funky values are compared? Perhaps there should be no funky values on the type in the first place?

Comment: Excellent point! Maybe all funky functions should always compare to equal and the result would be the same. This isn't some well thought "production code", but I just a moment ago found a code looks similar in spirit to what I'm striving to at [How do I create a job queue using a MailboxProcessor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041195/how-do-i-create-a-job-queue-using-a-mailboxprocessor). Let's see if I can provide more context to the question. As an aside, that ``MailboxProcessor`` is an interesting idea...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting a stack overflow in Equals, because you're using `=` on the same type you're implementing `Equals` for. So `Equals` calls `=`, `=` calls `Equals`, and so on...

What you want to do for `Equals` is this:

```
override this.Equals(o) =
    match o with
    | :? FunkyUnion as fu ->
        match this, fu with
        | Case1, Case1 | Case2, Case2 -> true
        | Funky f1, Funky f2 -> (* whatever you want to do for this case *)
        | _, _ -> false
    | _ -> false
```

You can update CompareTo in a similar way. This should get you started.

Comment: I'm editing... But yes, I got that much -- just phrased bit poorly. :) I was trying to come up something simple, simplish, to match the case. I'll update the question a bit and see if this gets me started.

Comment: I think this answers the main question. I need to do some research on the minor points. Cheers!